# finding data lying between a specific date range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find records from my database which lie between any user input date range(say between 10/2/2008 to 26/9/2024). I tried using

```
SELECT NAME
    ,TYPE
    ,COMP_NAME
    ,BATCH_NO
    ,SHELF
    ,MFG_DATE
    ,EXP_DATE
    ,QTY
    ,VAT
    ,MRP
FROM STOCK_LOCAL
WHERE 
    convert(VARCHAR(20), EXP_DATE, 103) 
        BETWEEN convert(VARCHAR(20), @MEDICINEEXP_DATE, 103)
            AND convert(VARCHAR(20), @MEDICINEEXPDATE, 103)
```

but with this query i need to enter perfect date range which is available in my database, it is not giving me data lying in between any date entered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you need to convert any of your date in where clause.let it simply be just date. where exp_date between @@MEDICINEEXP_DATE and @@MEDICINEEXPDATE.If still it is not runing then that may be no data between date.

Comment: because the EXP_DATE is "nchar" type.. for which i have to convert it.. and i am not suppose to change the data type from nchar to any other form

Comment: THen likely it gets converte dto the wrong dates because it's formatting as string is odd. People using nvarchar for dates often also have no clue how to format a date well as a string so it is - usable.

Comment: it will help if you mention date is store in which format.and in which format you pass data  ?

Comment: @user3032171 - Then you're in trouble.  Style 103 is `'dd/mm/yyyy'`.  However, if you order the STRINGs `'02/12/2013'` and `'01/01/2014'` then the string starting `01` will come before the string starting `02`, regardless of the month or year!  You ***must*** convert the string to a date, and then do the comparison; even if that's in the SQL statement.  ***Do Not*** convert dates to strings and then try to compare them, they won't be in the right order.  Also, if you don't change the string to a date in the table, performance will *always* suck, it will be *impossible* to improve.

Comment: i can understand but can't help it. have to work with the same form if any possibility kindly post here...

Comment: @user3032171 Post some dates stored in your database so someone can get idea and will help you.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using [BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially in SQLServer.  Ideally, avoid the use of `BETWEEN` altogether - the only type it's logically safe to use with is integral types (and avoid that for consistency).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a poolr designed schema there isnt going to be any decent/Efficient solution for this.

In sql server if you are storing Date or Date & Time data. Use the Data or DATETIME datatypes for your columns.

In your case you are trying to compare a string with passed date. and even when you tried to convert the string (Date) into date datatype you didnt do it correctly.

My suggestion would be Add new columns to your table with Date datatype and update these columns with existing date/string values.

For now you can convert the Date(string) into date datatype using the following code.

```
DECLARE @MEDICINEEXP_DATE DATE = 'SomeValue1'
DECLARE @MEDICINEEXPDATE  DATE = 'SomeValue1'

SELECT query....
FROM TableName
WHERE 
    CAST( 
         RIGHT(EXP_DATE, 4)
        +SUBSTRING(EXP_DATE,CHARINDEX('/',EXP_DATE)+1,2)
        +LEFT(EXP_DATE,2) 
        AS DATE)  >= @MEDICINEEXP_DATE
AND CAST( 
         RIGHT(EXP_DATE, 4)
         +SUBSTRING(EXP_DATE,CHARINDEX('/',EXP_DATE)+1,2)
         +LEFT(EXP_DATE,2) 
         AS DATE)  <= @MEDICINEEXPDATE
```

**Note**

This solution will get you the expected results but very inefficient method. It will not make use of any indexses on your EXP_DATE Column even if you have a very buffed up index on that column.